# fnTables() in jQuery is undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get all tables (which are dataTables) on a page,

**CODE:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if($.fn.dataTable)
    {
        var tables = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables();
    }
});
```

Getting the following error,

> has no method 'fnTables'

`$.fn.dataTable` is defined and no errors there, so, I searched for `fnTables` in the `jquery.dataTables.js` file and I **couldn't find it**.

But, `.fnTables()` is THE way to do what I want as per the [datatables site](http://www.datatables.net/api).

What can I do?

DataTable version is 1.9.0

Comment: could be Jquery conflict.

Comment: can you show how you are including the js files for dataTables?

Comment: i had this issue once, i was including js for datatables and another js for menu and i was getting the same error so i removed the js for datatable and started to use one, it solved.

Comment: @Nomi the normal way, in `<script>` tags, jQuery first, dataTable follows. not using any library apart from jQuery

Comment: @badZoke a jsfiddle will surely help us in debugging the code

Comment: Have you initialised the tables first? 

    $('#yourID').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"lTfr>t<"F"ip>'
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is there is no `fnTables()` method is dataTables 1.9.0.

I just downloaded and had look at the new files (1.9.4) and it **has** the `.fnTables()` method.

Pity, it's not documented on the site though.

Comment: Working fiddle in 1.9.4 http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/bj5pR/, same is broken with 1.9.0. The docs on the site reference only the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialised the tables first?

```
$('#ss_list').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": '<"H"lTfr>t<"F"ip>'.
    // ...
});

var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
if ( table.length > 0 ) {
    alert('You had created a dataTable!');
}
```

Comment: Yes I have initialized. So that's not the issue for sure. Please have a look at my answer, I guess it's a version issue.